# Get proc_dir_entry of /proc directly

Tags: c, linux, kernel, proc

I could use following code to get the /proc entry, but how to get the /proc entry directly? Any function in the kernel to do this directly(without creating one dummy sub-entry)?

```
  new_proc = proc_create("dummy", 0644, 0, &fileops_struct);
  root = new_proc->parent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a function, but you might access `proc_root` directly.

It is located in [fs/proc/root.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/root.c?id=refs/tags/v3.13#n240) and should be accessible from outside.

Comment: How could I refer to proc_root in my module source flie? I run into this error 'referencing pointer to incomplete type'.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I guess you need to include `fs/proc/internal.h`.